# Vertical labels with google charts API?

Tags: api, charts, graph, google-visualization

Anyone know how to get x-axis labels to be vertical with google charts API?

I need to fit a lot of labels in a small chart.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API does not provide anyway to get verticle x-axis labels (unless i missed it cause i need it too) what we did was a combination of datapoint point labels and regular x-axis labels - not perfect but works

Might try something like Dundas charts if you need more control

Comment: can you specify the rotation for a data point label?  do you have an example URL you can post?  thanks!

Comment: Nope there is nothing i have ever found to rotate any of the labels

Comment: for the viewer purpose, it is now available, see milind Morey answers.

Answer (score 99):

Add parameter options with slantedtextangle:90 degree to show label vertically

```
var options ={ hAxis: {title: "Years" , direction:-1, slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:90 }}
```

Comment: direction -1 is unrelated and will inverse the h axis

Comment: Thanks for this solution but Any idea how to wrap the text.. in my case it is big.

Comment: For slanted lables: hAxis: { slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:45 },

Answer (score 18):

this is a bit of an old thread.  but i was searching for this myself and came across this...

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#Configuration_Options

Look for: hAxis.slantedTextAngle and hAxis.slantedText.  Set your angle to 90 for vertical display (or anything in between for a slant).

Answer (score 17):

Diagonal Text here. This is my way of doing it, I hope it will help them.

https://jsfiddle.net/8tvm9qk5/

The code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

and

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);

function drawStacked() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Departamentos');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Entregados');
      data.addColumn('number', 'En Stock');

      data.addRows([
        ['abdasdasa', 925, 786],
        ['bbdasdas', 652, 156],
        ['cbdasdas', 300, 200],
        ['ddasdasb', 925, 786],
        ['edasdb', 652, 156],
        ['fasdasb', 300, 200],
        ['gdasdasdb', 925, 786],
        ['abdasdasa', 925, 786],
        ['bbdasdas', 652, 156],
        ['cbdasdas', 300, 200],
        ['ddasdasb', 925, 786],
        ['edasdb', 652, 156],
        ['fasdasb', 300, 200],
        ['gdasdasdb', 925, 786]


      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
        isStacked: true,
        height:600,
        chartArea: {
            height:300,
          top:100,
        },
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Departamentos',
          titleTextStyle: {
            color: '#FF0000',            
          },

          slantedText:true,
          slantedTextAngle:45,

        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Kits'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

It is possible now

```
var options = {
  title: "Test",
   hAxis: {
        direction:-1,
        slantedText:true,
        slantedTextAngle:90 // here you can even use 180
    }
};
```

Answer (score 12):

Another possible way you can "work around" this issue is to add an x axis:

```
chxt=x,y
```

could change to:

```
chxt=x,y,x
```

(Make sure anything you did to your original x axis has the same applied) then set your labels every other in one axis and every other offset by one in the other x axis (or every third depending on how long your labels are).

```
chx1=0:|Alpha||Gamma||Epsilon||Eta|2:||Beta||Delta||Zeta
```

Note the two || for an empty label between.  That way on your graph the labels switch off axises and you have a little more space:

```
Alpha    Gamma    Epsilon    Eta
    Beta      Delta      Zeta
```

Answer (score 3):

I've **not** find a way to rotate the axis, however, what I've done is shorten the labels and then create a legend to explain what the labels actually represent.

Click [here](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chs=500x300&chd=t:50,60,80,40,20,40,30&chxt=x,y&chxl=0%3a|A|B|C|D|E|F|G&chdl=A%3DStupidTest1|B%3DStupidTest2|C%3DStupidTest3|D%3DStupidTest4|E%3DStupidTest5|F%3DStupidTest6|G%3DStupidTest7) for a sample Google chart.

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

Set hAxis.slantedText to true and then set hAxis.slantedTextAngle=90.
Like so...

```
var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    ac.draw(data, {
      title : 'Equipment Performance Chart',
      isStacked:true,
      vAxis: {
        viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
        viewWindow: {
            max: 100
            },
        title: "Percentage"
        },
      hAxis: {
        title: "Area",
        slantedText:true,
        slantedTextAngle:90
        },
      seriesType: "bars",

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick is in the chartArea.height = 300  and chartArea.top = 100, height:600

```
var options = {
    title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
    isStacked: true,
    height:600,
    chartArea: {
        height:300,
        top:100,
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Departamentos',
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#FF0000',            
      },

      slantedText:true,
      slantedTextAngle:45,

    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Kits'
    }
  };
```