# Google Charts - change axis title orientation

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using a simple Line Chart from Google Charts.

I have two problems:

- Vertical and horizontal axis have a title. But I can't change their orientation. I want the vertical title written horizontally instead of vertically.
  vAxis and hAxis don't seem to have orientation options, any tips?
- The same for horizontal legend. it is written horizontally and transforming en diagonal when there are a lot of info. I want to writes it everytime en diagonal.

So basically the two questions are the same. How to change the text orientation?

Thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a workaround for this. Already there is a question regarding this. You take a look at this [Vertical labels with google charts API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786789/vertical-labels-with-google-charts-api). Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. We are thinking about "highcharts". Do you have any feedback about it?

Answer (score 8):

It is possible now:

```
var options = { 
    title: "Test", 
    hAxis: { 
        direction: -1, 
        slantedText: true, 
        slantedTextAngle: 90 // here you can even use 180 
    } 
};
```

Comment: the hAxis.direction option impacts on the sorting of the values, it does not have anything to do with the direction of the text

Answer (score 1):

There's no way, currently, to rotate the vertical axis title, sorry.

As far as transforming the titles in the horizontal axis, you're in an edge case whether your graph is continuous or discrete. If your data is discrete, you can use the [`slantedText`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) option. So, to summarize, make sure you have [`discrete`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Discrete_vs_Continuous) data, and set the above option.