# how can i edit google charts view in googlechart api?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

[image: this is how its look like i want to add some text in red circle]

this is html/javascript  for this bar

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
          ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
          ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
          ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
          ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

how can i edit this chart?i want to add some text as shown in screenshot in this chart.is there any way to edit this??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical labels with google charts API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786789/vertical-labels-with-google-charts-api)

Comment: have you tried the [`vAxis.title` configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options)?