# Change chart y-axis text orientation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to change my Google Chart's y-axis title to horizontal orientation. Currently, it is drawn with vertical writing, as shown in this image:

[image: my chart xaxis title]

My chart drawing code

```js
function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(temp);

    var options = {
        title: 'Report',
        //   vAxis: {title: 'Cups'},
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Date'
        },
        seriesType: 'bars',
        series: {
            0: {
                targetAxisIndex: 0
            },
            1: {
                targetAxisIndex: 1,
                type: 'line'
            }
        },
        vAxes: {
            0: {
                title: '報酬額',
                titleTextStyle: {
                    italic: false,
                }
            },
            1: {
                title: '再生',
                titleTextStyle: {
                    italic: false,
                }
            },
        },
        'chartArea' : {'width': '70%', left: '15%'}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical labels with google charts API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786789/vertical-labels-with-google-charts-api)

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the [Axis Overview](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes):

> Direction - You can customize the direction using the
>   hAxis/vAxis.direction option.
>
> hAxis.direction    The direction in which the values along the
>   horizontal axis grow. Specify -1 to reverse the order of the values.
>
> Type: 1 or -1 Default: 1

If this didn't answer the question, try the workarounds from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786789/vertical-labels-with-google-charts-api).

Comment: Pretty sure OP is looking to change the text rotation

Comment: i mean 'just change yaxis title'. but it did reversed all chart.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this. And works well. I don't think this is pretty way. 
If anyone find better way Please say to me thanks.

```
var textTags = document.getElementsByTagName("text");
        var searchPlay = "Play";
        var searchProfit = "Profit"

        $.each(textTags, function(index,value){
            if (value.textContent == searchPlay) {
                $(this).css('transform','rotate(1turn)');
                console.log(value);
            }
            if (value.textContent == searchProfit) {
                console.log(value);
                $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(1turn)');
            }
        });
```